# Reverse asterisks right triangle, java program

Tags: java

I am very close to this, however instead of the asterisks being horizontal, in a row, they are vertical, one in top of the other.

Question: Write a program that displays the output below. Use a variable to store the value for the number of asterisks in the first row. You must use multiple loops in your solution.

```
**********
*********
********
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

I currently have:

```
public class JavaAssignment6b {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        for(int r = 1; r <= 10; r++) {
            for(int j = 10; j >= r; j--) {
                System.out.println("*");
            }
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.print("*");` instead of `System.out.println("*");`

Comment: Remember, always debug your code to see where it is breaking. Read more about using and IDE and debugging code.

Comment: @D.R. do you want it to be centered?

Comment: @D.R. I posted TWO solutions below, one prints the number of asterisks on the first line, the other on every line.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer to this question. All you have to do is add a simple `if` statement. I have posted two solutions below, one prints the number of asterisks on the first line, the other posts the number of asterisks on every line.

### Solution 1

To print the number of asterisks on the *first* line:

```
int numberOfAsterisks = 0;
    for(int r = 1; r <= 10; r++) {
        for(int j = 10; j >= r; j--) {
            System.out.print("*");
            numberOfAsterisks++;
         }    
         if (r==1) {
            System.out.print(numberOfAsterisks);
         }
            System.out.println();
    }               
}
```

And the output

```
**********10
*********
********
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

---

### Solution 2

To print the number of asterisks on *every* line:

```
int numberOfAsterisks = 0;
                for(int r = 1; r <= 10; r++) {
                    for(int j = 10; j >= r; j--) {
                        System.out.print("*");
                        numberOfAsterisks++;
                    }
                    System.out.print(numberOfAsterisks);
                    numberOfAsterisks = 0;
                    System.out.println();
        }               
    }
```

and the output for this answer:

```
**********10
*********9
********8
*******7
******6
*****5
****4
***3
**2
*1
```